# How to get primaryKey for new Object in Realm?

Tags: android, realm

I start use `Realm` - and I have a lot of questions.

I want create new item:

```
class Item extends RealmObject {
     @PrimaryKey
     int id;
     // ...
}
```

Now I want create new Item, this line from Realm-docs:
[image]

In this examples they set 42 for id.

But **how to get in real life value for PrimaryKey in new Item object?**

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getNextPrimaryKey(RealmObject ob) { // ob extneds RealmObject
    int primaryKey = 1;
    try {
        primaryKey = realm.where(ob.getClass()).max(Constants.ID).intValue() + 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if table for this item is empty
    }
    return primaryKey;
}
```

Comment: That would work. This would be more efficient: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/469#issuecomment-182897019 There is also other suggestions in that issue.

Comment: Setting up the atomic integer is a hassle, if I made a new project where I *need* auto-increment IDs for whatever reason, I'd use this solution instead (in a transaction of course).